# htaccess pagination problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

1st ever post, so please be gentle... My main drag has been getting a php script to work correctly with my .htaccess file. I have scoured numerous posts on here and elsewhere and still its left me pulling my hair out... Probably missing something big time.

Okay here goes... Within my .htaccess file I have the following to try and work with multiple querystrings to help display procucts within a pagination script

```
RewriteRule    ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ get-products.php?cat_name=$1&pagination=$2    [NC,L]
```

The url displays correctly

```
products/dresses?page=10
```

But, no matter what I try the page never moves onto the next recordset pulled from the database when I click on the pagination links at the bottom

Comment: does the link successfully change to ..`page=11`?

Comment: then the issue is not he .htacess rule but your pagination script

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)` and make sure you get the variables in right.

Comment: The var_dump returned the following `code` array(2) { ["cat_name"]=> string(7) "dresses" ["pagination"]=> string(0) "" } page =

Comment: So that's telling myself that the pagination string is not getting captured

Comment: Okay I managed a hack using `code` $what_i_need = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $page = substr($what_i_need, strpos($what_i_need, "=") + 1); `code` to get the page number and it works but this isn't my preferred way of runningthis script